# Anyone know how to configure pybitcointools to bitcoin testnet?

Tags: pybitcointools

Anyone know how to configure https://github.com/wizardofozzie/pybitcointools
to bitcoin testnet?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is `blockr_fetch(txindex, "testnet")` and `blockr_push(signedTx, "testnet")`. Note the need to use "testnet" as the 2nd parameter.

[Reference](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/issues/91)

Comment: thank you Zombie, I will try. Would you please recommend a stable pybitcointools fork. I tried several already, can't find a stable one. or any python bitcoin tool you suggest to use?

Comment: you can look into this: https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib and https://github.com/alexanderjsingleton/crypto-cuck-coin

Comment: @kiwichen also check https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools